# QGIS Raster subtraction giving 0.005 value off from correct value

Tags: raster-calculator

I have two synthetic DEMs I have created to test a method of detecting changes.  I am using the Raster Calculator to subtract the first DEM from the second DEM.  The formula is simple, just 
"first_DEM - second_DEM".
I have set my Z value to 100.0000 for 90% of the DEMs.  The other 10% is 50.0000 for first_DEM and 40.0000 for second_DEM.  The results should be 0 over 90% of the DEM and 10.000 over 10%, which should show up when I calculate the histogram of pixel value vs. frequency in the resulting raster properties.  Instead, I get 90% at 0.005 and 10% at 9.995.  The two DEMs are exactly the same size at the same geographic location with the only differences in values being the 10.000 change over 10%.

Why is the calculator adding 0.005 to the majority of my pixel values, and subtracting 0.005 from the other 10%, when I'm only asking it to subtract the two DEMs?

Comment: I am trying to reproduce the issue you have encountered. Could you add information: (1) the tool you used to calculate the histogram, and the bin size, (2) the dimension (rows and columns) of the input rasters, and (3) the value for NoData cells? Thanks.

Comment: Absolutely!  For calculating the histogram, I am just using the tool in QGIS.  Layer properties > histogram > calculate histogram.
The input rasters dimensions are 95 rows and 60 columns.
The NoData value is 0.000.
Additionally, I have tried this in both QGIS 3.0.1 and 3.6.3.  I also ran the difference rasters through a python script that independently extracts the min/max values of the pixels, which do not appear to replicate the 0.005 error.  So, it may be in the histogram calculation and not the raster calculator.

Comment: Thanks! I now confirm strange histogram 'shift' on the  `Layer properties > histogram > calculate histogram` as you have mentioned. Using my 10x10 grid sample, I observe 0.05/9.95 pair. It seems QGIS adopted `square-root choice` to define the number of bins, and rounding it to closest power of ten. In your case, bin size is set to 0.01 (so the values fall between 0-0.01 will be plotted to the middle point: 0.005).

Comment: Instead of the histogram on the layer properties panel, I would suggest to try either `Raster layer histogram` or `Zonal histogram`, both in the Processing Toolbox.

Comment: @Kazuhito - Thank you!  That would explain the differences.I will try the other histograms and see if they will serve my purpose better.